# Use prometheus query result from a different query in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana

How do I use prometheus query result from a different query in the same panel in Grafana.

Example,

I have 3 Prometheus queries in Grafana,

1. `sum(increase(metric1[1h]))` say, `#A`
2. `sum(increase(metric2[1h]))` say, `#B`

Now, in the 3rd query I want to calculate the percent difference using the two results, similar to what we were able to do using Graphite metrics.

`(#B - #A)/#A`

How can I achieve this since Grafana does not seem to recognise these identifiers in Prometheus queries.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Click on the "Transform" tab
2. Click on the "Add transformation" button
3. Choose the "Add field from calculation" option
4. Select "Mode" = "Binary operation" and the desired operation

Note: you can use two transformations to get "(B - A) / A".

See the following example:

[image]